# Incorrect argument label in call (have 'frame:', expected 'coder:')

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

It is working in UIView but not in ViewController, I am getting this error "Incorrect argument label in call (have 'frame:', expected 'coder:')", How to solve this one. Please check attache image

[image]

```
 init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear

    currentMonthIndex = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date()) - 1
    currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
    setupViews()
    btnLeft.isEnabled=true
}
```

super.init(frame: frame) I am getting error for this line

Comment: Please attach code here

Comment: pls tap to double click in warning you get solution

Comment: Yeah @Anton i added image and code please check

Comment: @Jigar i get some solution but not able to solve

Answer (score 5):

`UIViewController` doesn't contain frame init it's for a `UIView` element only either

```
let myViewController = MyViewController( )
```

or

```
let myViewController = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)
```

//

```
class myViewController:UIViewController {

  // put here the properties 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.view.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
       currentMonthIndex = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date()) - 1
       currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
       setupViews()
       btnLeft.isEnabled=true
  }
}
```

Comment: @Appu if you want to create custom UIViewController remove init method and put the code in viewDidLoad